# Play JPA Query Example

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

How to get JPA work in Play MVC. I tried a lot of variants. But all unsuccesfull.

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void book() {
        EntityManager em = JPA.em();
        List<Book> bookList = em.createNativeQuery("select * from book").getResultList();

        render( bookList );
    }


    public static void index() {
        render( );
    }
}
```

I got error like this:

*A JPA error occurred (The JPA context is not initialized. JPA Entity Manager automatically start when one or more classes annotated with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation are found in the application.):*

Second variant doesnt' work:

*@NamedQuery(name = "findFoo", query = "select f from Foo f where f.state in :stateInList")*

*final Query query = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("findFoo");*

How to get worked with NamedQuery ?? Where to place NamedQuery ??

Comment: Have you annotated Book class?

Answer (score 0):

your named query is correct and you can write it above the entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Foo")
@NamedQuery(
{
    @NamedQuery(name = "findFoo", query = "select f from Foo f where f.state in :stateInList")
)}
public class Foo
{
 ....

}
```

Comment: A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Repeated column in mapping for entity: models.Book column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: use insertable=false,updateable=false in the coulmn id where it has been mapped to other entity  --- to resolve this error